# Define CSS style for single input ID, instead of input[type=checkbox]

Tags: css, input, checkbox

This is my check box

```
<input type="checkbox" name="MyName[]" value="A1" id="A1"/>
<label for="Filter"></label>
<input type="checkbox" name="MyName[]" value="A2" id="A2"/>
<label for="Filter"></label>
```

This is my style

```
input[type=checkbox] {..}
input[type=checkbox] + label {background:'image-1'}
input[type=checkbox]:checked + label {background:'image-2'}
```

I need to style EACH checkbox with a different checked and unchecked image.

I was thinking to refer to ID instead of `input[type=checkbox]` in my CSS.

How to do that?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
input#A1
input#A2
input#A1:checked
input#A2:checked
```

But you don't need to specify the tag name (`input`) if you don't want. But it can be useful though! (Especially with classes)

Read more about (ID-)selectors in the [docs](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#id-selectors).

Comment: I chose this answer becouse came first. I tested and it works.

Answer (score 3):

for

```
<input type="checkbox" name="MyName[]" value="A1" id="A1"/>
```

it will be

```
input[name=MyName[]] {..}
```

to satisfy your need

Comment: Ok I will check this too. Then I will rate.

Comment: I give an ID to the `input` and want to design it specifically.

how can I call it in css? `input[type="email"]#emailField{} `

Answer (score 2):

With the **id selector:** `#`

```
input#A1 {background:url('image-1.jpg');}
input#A1:checked {background:url('image-1-checked.jpg');}
input#A2 {background:url('image-2.jpg');}
```